# How to show downloading progressbar for imageview in Horizontal direction

Tags: android, android-progressbar, imagedownload

I am using google's API demo for downloading large bitmap efficiently. http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/androiddevelopers/samples/DisplayingBitmaps.zip

I want to show horizontal progressbar to show image downloading progress. Please anyone can help me to put horizontal progressbar in above demo example.

Comment: What have your tried so far? Show some code please.

Comment: Actually i don't get any idea in which class i should try for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/) will help you in your request.

Comment: Thanx Michael. I can get the idea from this.